# queryFixtures always returns 0 results

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I implemented queryFixtures in the FixtureAdapter to be able to make "more complex" queries. I did it like this (it's CoffeeScript):

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend {
  revision: 13
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.extend {
    queryFixtures: (fixtures, query, type) ->
      console.log fixtures.get('length') # 2
      fixtures = fixtures.filter (item) ->
        for prop of query
          if item[prop] != query[prop]
            return false
        return true
      console.log fixtures.get('length') # 1
      return fixtures
  }
}
```

Here is my Profile model + fixtures:

```
App.Profile = DS.Model.extend {
  name: DS.attr('string')
  businessName: DS.attr('string')
  picture: DS.attr('string')
  isBusiness: DS.attr('boolean')
  conversations: DS.hasMany('App.Conversation')
}

App.Profile.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1
    name: 'Jon Snow'
    picture: 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRDMu58ECeoIUUSMNPCEwWv4QAp4fT1fxXNK5AxK15I6GsAiBLC5Rl50zuOGQsDOedXbfE'
    isBusiness: false
    conversations: [101, 102]
  }
  {
    id: 2
    name: 'Jaime Lannister'
    picture: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB_K_IfaK-da-TbwgoM1NogXSc7QPVlaxaET76D8sdMoxAd1C2WCvnsKIM8-sGFpmiPPQ'
    isBusiness: true
    businessName: 'Westeros Inc.'
    conversations: [103]
  }
]
```

For testing purposes, I make the query on Profile in the init method of the ApplicationRoute:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend {

  init: ->
    profiles = App.Profile.find { isBusiness: false }
    console.log profiles.get('length') # 0 ??

  model: ->
    return App.Profile.find()

}
```

As you see, I logged fixtures.get('length') at different places.

The first console.log in the adapter returns "2" which is the total amout of profiles (OK).
The second console.log in the adapter returns "1" which means the filter is working (OK).
But what I don't understand is why do the third console.log in the router return "0". It's like data is not returned correctly...

I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong, if it's a bug in Ember Data, or if it's an expected behavior. Any ideas?

FYI, here is my Ember configuration:

```
Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.6
Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.4
jQuery.VERSION : 2.0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console.log outputs length 0 because fixtureAdapter is simulating an asynchronous query. To log query result size to console, use `then` like:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend {

  init: ->
    profiles = App.Profile.find { isBusiness: false }
    profiles.then (data) ->
      console.log 'count: ', data.get('length') # 1

  model: ->
    return App.Profile.find()

}
```

JSBIN here: http://jsbin.com/utasuh/1/edit